# Как почистить кеш в хроме?

Tags: google-chrome

В общем, был один Angular проект, который хостился по адресу:
http://localhost:2021/

При переходе в корень http://localhost:2021/ он перебрасывал на http://localhost:2021/projects

Теперь я запускаю другой сайт по этому адресу, но Chrome перекидывает меня в http://localhost:2021/projects, как я понимаю по кешу... Я нажимаю CTRL+F5, но кеш не зачищается по нему... Не хочу целиком удалять кеш по всем сайтам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажать Ctrl+Shift+I , затем, оставив открытой панель разработчика, ПКМ по кнопке "обновить эту страницу", которая слева от адресной строки, и выбрать нужный вам вариант

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это помогло.

Comment: если честно, то не знал о таком функционале до вашего вопроса:)